# How to calculate vector-wise dot product in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I hope to calculate a vector wise dot product in Keras. 
In detail, I mean if I have two tensor `A` and `B`, both with shape `(None, 30, 100)`, I want to calculate the result C with shape `(None, 30, 1)` which would satisfy

```
C[:,:,i] = dot(A[:,:,i], B[:,:,i]).
```

I wonder if that is possible, since the `batch_dot()` function in the backend would only return the shape `(None, 30, 30)` and only have the relationship

```
C[:,i,j] = dot(A[:,:,i], B[:,:,j])
```

But that is not what I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your output really (None, 30, 1)? Or is it (None, 30, 100)?

Comment: It should be (None, 30, 1) since the dot product of two 100 dimension vectors is a scalar. I may have not describe the problem clearly enough. By element-wise, I have regarded those 100 dimensions vectors as an element.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like:

```
import keras.backend as K

C = K.sum(A * B,axis=-1,keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the tensor in Keras support the ' * ' operation?

Comment: Yes, it's an elementwise multiplication. The result is the same shape as the originals. Then you sum the last axis.

Comment: By the way, could you tell me where is the ' * ' operation in the document of Keras? Or it is a tensorflow operation?

Answer (score 2):

The `batch_dot` function is right for you, just include the correct axis. Assuming that `A.shape = (2,3,4)` and `B.shape = (2,3,1)`, you will get `C` that has shape `(2,4,1)`.

```
C = K.batch_dot(A, B, axes=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it does not correspond to my problem. It may have confusion in my description and I have edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you give an example by taking two matrices and do what you want to do in Numpy?