# Is it really that difficult to return a scalar dot product in Keras (tf backend)?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I've already asked this question on [Keras issues](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7618) but since I've gotten no answers there I decided to try my luck here.

I'm running the [mnist mlp example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) with a custom optimizer which for the time being is just a carbon copy of SGD from [optimizers.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py), i.e.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Optimizer
from keras import backend as K
from legacy import interfaces
import numpy as np

class testsgd(Optimizer):
..... [everything same as sgd] .....

myopt = testsgd()

....[define model]....

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=myopt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Now, in my custom optimizer I need to compute the dot product of the gradient with the velocity, i.e. after line [168](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L168) in optimizers.py, I need something similar to

`angle = K.dot(g,v)`

or
`angle = K.dot(K.transpose(g),v)`

or
`angle = K.dot(g, K.transpose(v))`

Unfortunately none of the above work, I just get the error

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [512], [512].

I understand that `g` and `v` are tensors which perhaps might need to be flattened to numpy arrays so as to use numpy for the dot product.

The closest that I came was by inspecting line [75](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L75) in optimizers.py, which calculates the norm of the gradient, i.e.

```
norm = K.sqrt(sum([K.sum(K.square(g)) for g in grads]))
```

However, even then, the statement

`print(norm)`

still returns a tensor!

Similarly I have also tried

```
angle = K.sum(g * v,axis=-1,keepdims=True)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853741/how-to-calculate-vector-wise-dot-product-in-keras) but still the result is a tensor which I cannot interpret as correct or not:

> Tensor("Sum_2:0", shape=(1,), dtype=float32)

When I try

```
print (K.get_value(angle))
```

I just get

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions
>      [[Node: dense_4_input = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I don't know how `keras` implements these functions.  In `numpy` `transpose` of a 1d array changes nothing (swapping one dimension with itself).  `dot` for 1d arrays does the vector inner product, giving a scalar.  `matmul` (`@`) is deligates to `dot` for 1d arrays.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I'm facing something similar

Answer (score 1):

Use `K.get_value(x)` to get scalar of a tensor.

[tf.keras.backend.get_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/get_value)